# htaccess code causing problems with links on server?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've implemented the htaccess code below for my website.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from /category.php?id=name&phrase=something to /name/something
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+category\.php\?id=([^&]+)&phrase=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L]

# skip files and directories from rewrites
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Cleans up all the article, and wrestler pages
RewriteRule ^/?article/([^/]+)/?$ article.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?wrestler/([^/]+)/?$ wrestler.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

# Removes the .php extension from pages
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# For the redirecion of related topics links on wrestler profile pages
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ category.php?id=$1&phrase=$2 [L,QSA]

#IGNORE CODE BELOW, IT IS ALL COMMENTED OUT
#For homepage redirections. It works if added at very front of code, but overall problem still not solved (links hovered over show true link)
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+article\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ article/%1? [R=302,L]

#internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^article/([^/]+)/?$ article.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

The problem that I'm having is that when I have a link on my website as

```
www.domain.com/
```

is automaticaly makes it

```
http://domain.com/wrestler/www.domain.com/
```

Even if it is

```
www.domain.com
```

(Note no "/" at the end of domain, it still makes it redirect to the link above. This should not be happening. I'm quite confused as to what is causing this. What should I do?

Comment: Doesn't look like it happening due these rules shown. Can you try in a different browser?

Comment: I have, and I even tried deleting cache.

Comment: For testing rename this .htaccess to something else and see if same behavior continues.